# Storing first half of string in variable

Tags: python

Im going through the pycharm educational edition for fun, and I am stuck on a technical error. I am trying to understand exactly what it wants. I have included a picture.

It is hinting that I need to convert the type. I have used len to count the string, which is 88, I am then printing out the first half of that string using slicing. However, it is hinting that I am missing the type conversion. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am curious

[image]

Comment: It is advisable to add code on page.

Comment: What do you want actually?

Comment: Have you assign string to `phrase` variable correctly? because in image string not end with triple quote.

Comment: I am specifically only supposed to use the len function,slicing, and type conversion. it must be done only on the box, on one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually use len in your solution- your code isn't WRONG, it is just not fulfilling what it's trying to teach you.  It is probably looking for something like

```
length = len(phrase)
first_half = phrase[0:length/2]
```

Comment: Yes exactly, I understand Im doing it ok, but I want to figure out what it WANTS me to do. Ill try this method, it also want me to convert the type.

Comment: Right- so you used len(phrase) on another page somewhere to get the count.  They just want you to use it in that task box.  (or so I am guessing- is the red box give you more info if you hover over it?)

Comment: How would I convert this from int to letters, using the SAME LINE first_half = len(phrase) / 2

Comment: means list of letters from first half part?

Comment: You could put first_half=phrase[0:len(phrase)/2] to combine them into one line.

Comment: can I convert this type on the same line? so that rather than printing out the numerical value it will print the string ? first_half = len(phrase) / 2

Comment: thank you paul I will try it , but it only allows for the functions its asking for specifically. I do appreciate your help, it just frustrating trying to figure out what It wants, as long as I understand the concept im fine.

Comment: The codecademy tutorials seem easier to follow then those.  Note from what I typed- the brackets aren't a function, they are slice notation.  The only function in there is len().  That is saying "Whatever is in phrase from the first character to half the length of phrase"

Comment: its annoying trying to figure out exactly what the tutorial wants but now I know that I can write it like that. Thanks again paul

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PyCharm Python3 returns a float when dividing it told me when I entered the same way. It wants you to put an int type conversion like so

first_half = phrase[0:int(len(phrase)/2)]

Answer (score 0):

Acceptable answer is;

```
phrase = """
It is a really long string
triple-quoted strings are used
to define multi-line strings
"""
first_half = phrase[:int(len(phrase)/2)]
print(first_half)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we specify [0:44], the interpreter does not take into account the 44 character. So I did this:

```
 first_half = str(phrase[0:((int(len(phrase)//2))+1)])
 print(first_half)
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
first_half = phrase[:int(len(phrase)/2)]
print(first_half)
```